# django-table2, метод render_foo без вывода None

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Все привет, подскажите, пожалуйста:
Я использую django-table2
если я использую empty_values=(), то у меня работает render_foo, но при этом в пустые поля выводится None, я бы хотел выводить прочерк, но если я этого добиваюсь с помощью empty_values=None, тогда render_foo работать не будет в соответствии с документацией.

Подскажите, как мне выполнить оба условия, чтобы и render_foo работал и выводился прочерк?

P.s.: `default='—'` также не помогает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы не укажите `empty_values=()`, то метод `render_` работать не будет. Далее вы можете проверить наличие `value`, и если его нет, заменить результат `None`, на `'—'`:

```
field = tables.DateColumn(empty_values=(),)


def render_field(self, value, record, column):
        if not value:
            return '—'
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]